# Create VM snapshots using power CLI with no memory quiesce

Tags: scripting, snapshot, vsphere, powercli, vcenter

I need to have a script to run in vcenter power CLI for creating VM snapshots.

Below is the requirement.I am new to scripting.Can someone please help me to do this.

1. server names should be taken from a text/csv file.
2. snapshot should be created with the name we are giving and also with no memory quiesce (equivalent to uncheck the 'snapshot the virtual machine's memory' option in GUI, I believe.).
3. VM name, created snapshot name,creation date and status (successful or failed) should be exported to an output csv file.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code??? I will not write the entire script for you, but you have to connect to a vCenter, use get-vm and then you can use:

New-Snapshot [-Name]  [-Description ] [-Memory] [-Quiesce] [-RunAsync] [-VM]  [-Server ] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] []

Here is the reference: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/New-Snapshot.html